# Get jSON data from other URL using AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I am trying to GET jSON data from external link using AJAX and for reason its not printing the output. I tried looking into many questions and tried in the following ways and none worked for me.

Test 1

```
$.ajax({
    "url":"http://20percents.com/created_by_mohan/testAll.php",
    "type":"GET",
    "data": { fields: "title" },
    "dataType":"jsonp",
    "contentType":"application/json",
    "jsonpCallback":"myCallback",
    "success":function(data){
        console.log(data);
        alert(data.title);
    }               
})
```

Test 2

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'http://20percents.com/created_by_mohan/testAll.php',
  type: 'GET',
  data:  { fields: "title" },
  success: function(data) {
    //called when successful
    $('body').html(data);
  },
  error: function(e) {
  }
});
```

Test 3

```
var mydata;
$.ajax({
   url: 'http://20percents.com/created_by_mohan/testAll.php',
   dataType: 'json',
   success: function(data) {
      mydata = data; 
      console.log(mydata);
   }
});
```

Test 4

```
$.ajax({
type:"GET", 
    url: "http://20percents.com/created_by_mohan/testAll.php", 
    success: function(data) {
            $("body").append(JSON.stringify(data));
        }, 
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert(jqXHR.status);
        },
   dataType: "jsonp"
});
```

I need to get some data for instance title, storeid, store-cuisines for now. How can I make this working?

Thanks

Comment: Why dont you use getJSON?

Comment: Are you sure that the remote endpoint supports JSONP? Or CORS? Otherwise you won't be able to call it due to the same origin policy restriction that's built into the browsers. You may take a look at the `console` of the browser. Usually such errors will be shown there.

Comment: Run your script in jsfiddle and open up the console tab in chrome debug tool. You will see the error: XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://20percents.com/created_by_mohan/testAll.php. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://fiddle.jshell.net' is therefore not allowed access. Fix that first. Follow @Darin's suggestion as well.

Answer (score 1):

### First you try the type of ajax data

```
 dataType: 'json'
```

If it didnt work then try post method with any security token.[or dummy post value]
You could use this.

### JQuery

```
 $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: 'test.php',
    dataType: 'json',

    success: function(response){
        console.table([response]);
    }
 });
```

If you've a json file you could read it using php fn. and echo it.

Comment: I don't know how this gonna work. I am looking for getting data and decoding it whereas you are proposing to post data and encode it.

Comment: Apologise I've edited the answer. Can you please try?.

Comment: @hoja.M.A : Please create a jsfiddle for this type of answers , Your answer is too generic and doesn't answer the question.

Comment: This is half answer, it would be great if you can make a fiddle. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
var url = "http://20percents.com/created_by_mohan/testAll.php?"
, data = {"fields":"titles"}
, results = $("#results")
, request = function(url, data) {
    results.text("requesting " + data.fields + "...");
    return $.getJSON("https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q="
      + "select * from json where url='" + url + $.param(data) + "'"
      + "&format=json&callback=")
};
request(url, data)
.then(function(data) {
  console.log(data)
  results.text(JSON.stringify(data.query.results.json.data, null, 4))
}, function(err) {
  console.log(err)
});
```

See [Working with JSONP](http://learn.jquery.com/ajax/working-with-jsonp/)

```js
var url = "http://20percents.com/created_by_mohan/testAll.php?"
, data = {"fields":"titles"}
, results = $("#results")
, request = function(url, data) {
  results.text("requesting " + data.fields + "...");
return $.getJSON("https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q="
  + "select * from json where url='" + url + $.param(data) +"'"
  + "&format=json&callback=")
};
request(url, data)
.then(function(data) {
  console.log(data)
  results.text(JSON.stringify(data.query.results.json.data, null, 4))
}, function(err) {
  console.log(err)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<pre id="results"></pre>
```